# Scrollable <iframe> in Safari

Tags: html, css, iframe, svg

I have a page with an image viewing box which must show SVG images dynamically loaded with Ajax. Any image can have some links to other SVGs (it's like an interactive map) which should be loaded into the same view box. It should also have fixed screen size and be scrollable, so I use a simple `<iframe width=... height=...>` with `overflow:scroll` as a container. That works as intended in Chrome; hovewer, there is a strange behaviour in desktop Safari, where the image gets auto-resized to the frame border no matter which layout attributes I've tried. Is that a bug, or some specific parameters are needed?

**UPDATE**

added a demo. The picture keeps its original size and can be scrolled in Chrome, but is resized in Safari. Chrome demonstrates another weird bug with scroll bars (they aren't redrawn when moved), but that's unrelated.

```html
<iframe src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Vector-based_example.svg" style="width:128px; height:128px; overflow:scroll"></iframe>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson please take a look.

Comment: @RachelGallen Version 7.1.8 (9537.85.17.9.1)

Comment: try this and see if it works http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/vfb4cpgc/

Comment: @RachelGallen Sadly my Safari (which is the same version as Yuuri's) still seems to screw that up.